# How to move files based on a list (which contains the filename and destination path) in terminal?

Tags: directory, structure, rsync

I have a folder that contains a lot of files. In this case images.
I need to organise these images into a directory structure.

I have a spreadsheet that contains the filenames and the corresponding path where the file should be copied to. I've saved this file as a text document named files.txt

```
+--------------+-----------------------+
| image01.jpg  |  path/to/destination  |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| image02.jpg  |  path/to/destination  |
+--------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm trying to use rsync with the `--files-from` flag but can't get it to work.

According to `man rsync`:

```
--include-from=FILE
This  option  is related to the --include option, but it specifies a FILE that contains include patterns (one per line).  Blank lines in the file and lines starting with ';' or '#' are ignored.  If FILE is  -, the list will be read from standard input
```

Here's the command i'm using: `rsync -a --files-from=/path/to/files.txt path/to/destinationFolder`

And here's the rsync error: `syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/options.c(1436) [client=2.6.9]`

It's still pretty unclear to me how the files.txt document should be formatted/structured and why my command is failing.

Any help is appreciated.